# Why did Trebuchet have so long throwing arms?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, projectile

Have a look at such an historical Trebuchet:

[image: Historical Trebuchets]

As you can see, the **throwing arm (left) is much longer than the weight arm (right)**.

Law of conservation of energy says, potential energy from the weight on the right ($E_{potR}$) is converted to kinetic and potential energy from the right.

$ E_{potR} = E_{potL} + E_{kinL}$

$ m_R\cdot g\cdot h_R= m_L \cdot g \cdot h_L + \frac{1}{2} m_L \cdot  v^2 $

From my understanding of this formula, **I want to have the most possible weight $m_R$ on the right side of the lever and therefore the weight arm should be long(er) than the throwing arm, as the falling distance $ h_R $ will increase.**

Why is this not the case?

Comment: Consider actually *building* one with a long weight arm.  You will very quickly realise why they are short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your notation right, then by $h_L$ you mean the height of the left weight? In that case your formula doesn't make sense: To account for energy conservation, you would have to take the heights before and afterwards of the right weight.   Then you get
\begin{align}
m_R*g*h_{before} = m_R*g*h_{after} + \frac{1}{2} m_L * v^2
\end{align}

You could argument that still, the difference of the heights depends on the length of your "weight-arm". That is true, but there is something ways more important to account for here: You forget that your weight is also accellerated, that makes an additional term in your formula:

\begin{align}
m_R*g*h_{before} = m_R*g*h_{after} + \frac{1}{2} m_L * v_L^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_R * v_R^2
\end{align}

The Energy will be splitted onto the two weights, and since they are connected by the arm, the velocities are not independent:
\begin{align}
v_R =\frac{l_R}{l_L} v_L
\end{align}

Plugging everything into the first equation:
\begin{align}
m_R*g*h_{before} = m_R*g*h_{after} + \frac{1}{2} m_L * v_L^2 + \frac{1}{2} m_R * (\frac{l_R}{l_L} v_L)^2 \\
m_R*g*(h_{before} - h_{after}) = v_L^2 \frac{1}{2} (m_L + \frac{l_R}{l_L}^2 m_R) \\
\frac{2*m_R*g*(h_{before} - h_{after})}{(m_L + \frac{l_R}{l_L}^2 m_R)} = v_L^2 
\end{align}

From this you see, that the longer your weight arm is (that means that $\frac{l_R}{l_L}$ will be bigger), the more energy will be spent on accellerating the weight. You don't want to accelerate the weight, but your projectile, and this is way more important than the additional energy you would get if you would increase the length of the weight arm.

Comment: $ h_L $ and $ h_R $ are the differences in height.

Comment: In that case I got you wrong there. Still the rest of the argumentation remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it would be impractical.

Your reasoning is basically correct: a longer right arm will grant you a larger $\Delta h$, increasing the speed of the projectile. But there would be some issues:

1. The structure would have to be higher, otherwise the weight would smash into the ground. Hence, it will be heavier and more difficult to carry.
2. The weight would gain substantial acceleration, and the structure could be compromised.
3. It would require much more energy to "recharge" the weapon.